# looping a template using groovy GStringTemplateEngine()

Tags: groovy, template-engine

My requirement is to **create a template engine to support a looping in it**.

The **final template** should look something like this:

```
#cat output.template 
env:
  - name : param1 
    value : 1
  - name : param2 
    value : 2
```

I have **pseudo code to explain my requirement**

```
def f = new File('output.template')
def engine = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine()

def mapping = [
    [ name : "param1",
      value : "1"],
    [ name : "param2",
      value : "2" ]
] // This mapping can consists of a multiple key value pairs.

def Template = engine.createTemplate(f).make(mapping) 

println "${Template}"
```

Can someone help me **how to achieve this requirement of looping inside the templates and how should I modify my template?**

***UPDATE : All the solutions provided by** `tim_yates` **or by** `Eduardo Melzer` **has resulted in following output with extra blank lines at the end of template. What could be the reason for that?*** Are the solution providers not able to see this behavior or the issue is my system only?.

```
# groovy loop_template.groovy 
env:
  - name: param1
    value : 1 
  - name: param2
    value : 2 


root@instance-1:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your template file to look like this:

```
#cat output.template
env:<% mapping.eachWithIndex { v, i -> %>
  - name : ${v.name}
    value : ${v.value}<% } %>
```

As you can see, your template file expects an input parameter called `mapping`, so you need change your main code to something like this:

```
    def f = new File('output.template')
    def engine = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine()

    def mapping = [
        [ name : "param1", value : "1"],
        [ name : "param2", value : "2"]
    ] // This mapping can consists of a multiple key value pairs.

    def Template = engine.createTemplate(f).make([mapping: mapping])

    println "${Template}"
```

Output:

```
#cat output.template
env:
  - name : param1
    value : 1
  - name : param2
    value : 2
```

Comment: It's ok and expected that a file ends with a new blank line, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline) for example. But, your result will just have blank lines, if your template file has it too.

Comment: @Here_2_learn Oh, and you can use `trim` on your result to remove spaces and blank lines. Like: `println "${Template}".trim()`

Comment: posted a continuation of this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514779/groovy-multiple-loops-in-template-engine-using-gstringtemplateengine, can you check and help me.